# Virtual Directory counterpart in nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, virtual-directory

It seems nginx does not support embeded `location` bloks. Does this mean there is no `VirtualDirectory` counterpart in nginx?

What is nginx conf of following Apache conf:

```
Alias /foo "D:\www\foo\public"
<Directory "D:\www\foo\public">
     # some settings
</Directory>
Alias /bar "D:\www\bar\public"
<Directory "D:\www\bar\public">
     # some other config
</Directory>
```

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias

Answer (score 10):

It would be:

```
location /foo/ {
    alias d:/www/foo/public/;
}
location /bar/ {
    alias d:/www/bar/public/;
}
```

Note that there is a longstanding bug that alias and try_files don't work together.

Comment: Thanks, I also need .php support in them.